# adjective + of-phrase + to-infinitive

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary

> Beside some of them he had jotted the letter A for Anstis, and if it had crossed Strike’s mind that it might be considered arrogant or deluded ***of*** a private detective with no authority in the investigation to imagine he had the power to delegate tasks to the police officer in charge of the case, the thought did not trouble him.
>   (The Silkworm, by Robert Galbraith)

At first, it’s a place for ‘*for*’ not ‘***of***', I thougt. Is it a pattern that if an adjective before ‘*of*’ has the property of *of*’s complement, and this *of-pp* denotes the agent of to infinitive as well, you use ‘*of*’ instead of ‘*for*,’ without exceptions?

Comment: Keep in mind that the default preposition is "of". And so, sometimes another preposition might be better, and sometimes "of" might not be acceptable, but overall, when in doubt, er, the preposition "of" is kinda like the default preposition. :)

Comment: This is really interesting! Google Ngram of `considered * of him` returned: *unworthy, worthy, characteristic*. Google Ngram of `considered * for him` returned: *necessary, safe, proper, unsafe, good, sufficient, that, best, advisable, prudent*. Based on these adjectives, the *of*-adjectives seem to be part of him or his characteristic, something he possesses. The *for*-adjectives seem to be more about third-person view. This supports F.E.'s "'of' is kinda like the default proposition".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might think it arrogant *of* me to ask, but do you love the works of Robert Galbraith?

It was rude of you to butt into the line ahead of people who have been waiting.

It is so kind of you to say so!

"For" would not work in the second or third sentence.

See OED ***of*** <del>III.</del>  V. 16.

Comment: I am using the teeny-tiny print version with a cheapo magnifying glass. Could be I miscounted.

Comment: section V.16 is correct. My apologies.